# NSString to NSDate no correct result

Tags: mysql, ios, core-data, nsdate

I get a date in String format through a web service via JSON, this date in mysql database is a TimeStamp field.

I get the date of the web service in this way **2013-09-24 20:30:00**

When I run the code to get a NSDate from NSString that get this **2013-09-24 18:30:00 +0000**

The code I use to do the parse is:

```
- (NSDate *)parseNSStringToNSDate:(NSString *)hora {
         NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
         [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
         return [dateFormatter dateFromString:hora];
  }
```

If you realize I have left two hours at all hours **and not know why**.
I have also been testing the time zone setting. Example:

```
- (NSDate *)parseNSStringToNSDate:(NSString *)hora {
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GTM"]];
return [dateFormatter dateFromString:hora];
```

}

Comment: You mean, you are getting wrong time ryt?

Comment: Are you simply logging the NSDate?? If so, then stop and look at the hundreds of other questions on this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do simply like.

```
- (NSDate *)parseNSStringToNSDate:(NSString *)hora {
     NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

     NSLocale * enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];

     [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
     return [dateFormatter dateFromString:hora];
  }
```